# No output from Xdebug with Serverpress (Desktopserver/visual studio Code) (localhost environment)

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, localhost, xdebug

I am trying to get xDebug running. It is included in serverpress.
I am starting serverpress (all running on localhost) and even when enabling the debug and trace feature I get no output in the debug and trace console. Also when using netstat (windows) I find that there is no process running on the port 9000.

Here a download link to an html with the output of phpinfo() with info about xDebug when run on the developmentSite running serverpress. (it is to big to include here as a snipped) Maybe Xdebug has not the right settings?

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah9AkzEZfTM4hGOcOyeEXYKy6P7m?e=6aYpGw

Here also the php.ini (with port and localhost settings) of the serverpress folder

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah9AkzEZfTM4hGhY_IKHN-JltMpK?e=2Qif3F

Also I was trying to use xDebug with Visual Studio code. Listening on the set port. But also no success. I guess if there is no process on the port 9000 its reasonable that no information is coming from there.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Version 2.7.0RC2" — You're running an old and unsupported *Release Candidate* of Xdebug. Please run the latest version. Also be aware that it is your IDE that needs to listen for incoming connections, that that Xdebug will not open a port for listening.

Comment: it is the latest serverPress installation. it comes bundled with xDebug. So you suggest I change the .dll there?

Comment: I installed now xampp instead but as soon as I add xdebug with the zend_extension in php.ini I cannot connect to localhost anymore and open my wordpress files. When I remove xdebug I can access my server on localhost without problems.

Comment: I got xampp with xdebug running! I switched to an older version of xampp (php7) and xdebug.dll. With php8 it didn't work.